# Does ORDER BY and WHERE clause have different precedence?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am currently fetching data using the statement

```
$queryfetchBookings="SELECT `id`,`sessionHeld`,`fk_student_id`,`channelName`,`video_duration`,`audio_duration`,`category`,`dateBooked`,`timeSlot`,`duration`,`category`,`studentName`,`overallRating`,`chat_duration`  FROM `one_to_one_bookings` WHERE fk_co_id=".$co_id;
```

I now want to add an

```
 ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

to the end but whatever variation I have tried results in failure.(Does not fetch data). Need advice on how to proceed.

Different variations that i have tried:
[image]

Comment: How and where do you put the _order by_ ??

Comment: @nacho I have added an image above that shows what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: Please be warned that the given query is widely open for SQL injection. You should better use prepared statements to avoid getting hacked. Also, if you are facing any "failure", please share more details, like the error messages in text form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection, and not concatenating strings to your query.

You are doing wrong your concatenation in **PHP**, you need to add a `.` and some quotes:

```
$queryfetchBookings="SELECT `id`,`sessionHeld`,`fk_student_id`,`channelName`,`video_duration`,`audio_duration`,`category`,`dateBooked`,`timeSlot`,`duration`,`category`,`studentName`,`overallRating`,`chat_duration`  
FROM `one_to_one_bookings` WHERE fk_co_id=".$co_id." ORDER BY `id` ASC";
```

The problem was at the end of the query:

```
WHERE fk_co_id=".$co_id." ORDER BY `id` ASC";
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how the server you are using works, but in oracle it would not work because after the WHERE clause you are adding a ";". At least in oracle this would mean that the query is over, so I am guessing this is why it is not considering your last sentence.
I hope I can help :)

Comment: Hi i am trying to insert that statement before the semicolon itself, I have added an image to my post which should give you a better idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi Daniel, welcome to stackoverflow. just take into account that the `;` the OP is using it is not for the SQL query, it is the end of line character needed in PHP code